# Подводить итоги — ЧЕМУ или ЧЕГО?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, выбор-варианта

Отвечала на вопрос; в [Нацкорпусе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8&kwsz=5&p=1&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) попалось вот такое предложение.

В том же 2007 году американские исследователи, **подводя итоги летнему сезону**, установили, что площадь льда была на 39 процентов меньше, чем средняя за минувшие 30 лет (с момента, когда впервые начались спутниковые измерения), и на 25 процентов меньше, чем в рекордном (до тех пор) 2005 году. [Яков Гольник. Арктика бьет рекорды и открывает новые возможности // «Знание-сила», 2013]

Подводя итоги (*чему?*) сезону. Или все-таки "*чего?*" — сезона? Или обе формы приемлемы?
Подскажите, друзья.

Answer (score 3):

"[Грамота](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%E8%F2%EE%E3)" приводит *обе* формы управления, цитируя "Большой толковый словарь" Кузнецова и "Управление в русском языке" Розенталя.
У Кузнецова в словарной статье на **Итог** дается выражение

> Подводить итоги чему-л. (делать выводы из чего-л.)

У Розенталя имеется такая статья:

> ИТОГ — подвести итоги / итог чего / чему. *Подвести итоги переговоров;*
> *Подводя итоги путешествия, спрашиваю себя о самом главном, что дала*
> *эта поездка (Пол.); Подвести итог своим расходам.*

Из этих примеров можно предположить, что **выбор** типа управления *зависит от контекста*: если "подводить итоги" употребляется в значении "**давать оценку** чему-л. (положительную, отрицательную, буквально количественную; делать выводы из чего-л.)", то уместно управление "подводить (итоги) чему", если же в качестве итогов подразумевается **перечень сделанного** за период, в процессе мероприятия (поездка, совещание, театральный сезон), то управление "итоги чего". В примере из вопроса речь идёт о количественной оценке интересующих исследователей процессов (управление подходит). Однако с "театральным сезоном" контексты могут различаться:

> 1. Подведем итог прошедшему сезон**у**: он был явно провальным.
> 2. Подведем итоги сезон**а**. Мы поставили несколько новых спектаклей, приняли в труппу интересных актеров... и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

А и так и сяк.

[Подводить и. чему-л.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3&all=x)

**Управление в русском языке**

> ИТОГ — подвести итоги / итог чего / чему. *Подвести итоги переговоров;
> Подводя итоги путешествия, спрашиваю себя о самом главном, что дала
> эта поездка* (Пол.); *Подвести итог своим расходам.*

Comment: Ах-ха! Вот где надо было смотреть! Спасибо, Галина. Но мне кажется, что в некоторых случаях есть все-таки какие-то предпочтения. Нет? Например, подвести итоги **недели**, подвести итоги **состязаний**, подводить итоги **конкурса**. Не могу себе представить: _неделе, состязаниям, конкурсу_.

Comment: "Управление в русском языке" - специально для таких предпочте-колебаний сорганизованный словарь, вот.