# Почему «подскажите», а не «скажите»?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Зачастую в обращениях старое доброе «*скажите*» звучит реже и реже. При том что числом вхождений «*подскажите*» в НКРЯ до 2000 г. можно было пренебречь, с недавних пор это слово лидирует (в том числе здесь на сайте) и редкий автор вопроса его не использует. В чём причины такой популярности? Видя смысловую разницу, не могу понять и чрезмерную тягу писать на три буквы больше необходимого.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50049/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%94%d0%a1%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%97%d0%90%d0%a2%d0%ac

Comment: Cпасибо, Серж! Искал повелительную форму и был уверен, что встречу. Не нашёл, не увидел. Ну ничего, бумага стерпит.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что это камушек в мой огород ([Подскажите, друзья](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466751/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%9C%D0%A3-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%93%D0%9E)).

Дело в том, что нейтральный глагол [сказать](http://www.endic.ru/academic/Skazat-58005.html) имеет множество значений, а глагол [подсказать](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Podskazat-29454.html) — всего два.
И эти значения в неофициальной беседе или дружеском разговоре таковы: порекомендуйте, посоветуйте, натолкните на мысль, разрешите сомнения, дайте знать, намекните...

Скажи, сколько букв в алфавите? — требование, приказ, указание.
Подскажи, что такое аквамарин? — ободряющая просьба.

Разве это плохо, когда к вам **так доверительно** обращаются за помощью, разве это дурно, паразитарно?
Я, например, в своем вопросе *специально* использовала и этот глагол, и такое обращение к посетителям сайта — хотелось хоть немного разрядить обстановку (ведь двое постоянных участников были вне игры), показать общность интересов.

Comment: Да нет, какие камушки? Ничего личного. На сайте, как я сказал, таких примеров — море. Насчёт «аквамарина» уместны: «Покажи, где тут...» и «Напомни, что такое...». И «ободряющее» в просьбе если и есть, то бодрит обращение на ты. Скорее, побуждающее.

Answer (score 1):

"...Не могу понять и чрезмерную тягу писать на три буквы больше необходимого." Может быть, в этом и суть. Просящий показывает, что ему не трудно сказать лишние буквы, ему не хочется быть прямым и жестким, а хочется как-то уйти от приказной формы, обойти ее. Подсказывают по своему желанию, из чистого альтруизма, а "скажите" - почти приказ. Я думаю, это от нежелания обидеть человека грубым требованием. Превращение требования в просьбу. Кстати, меня удивляет больше новая манера многих формулировать просьбы примерно так: "Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, достать мне книгу с полки". Звучит немного коряво, переизбыток вежливости. Но бывает и наоборот: одна моя подруга, наслушавшись гуру на дорогих семинарах, сказала, что нельзя начинать просьбы с частицы "не", иначе будут отказывать, поэтому она теперь старательно формулирует просьбы без "не", чтобы получать положительные ответы... Похоже, так люди и лавируют между крайностями, и пользуются всеми вариантами, которые есть в русском языке, в том числе разговорными и новыми, чтобы как можно точнее передать свои желания другим.

Comment: В основном речь велась о печатных словах. В т. ч. о почти полном отсутствии в речи иных уместных слов при обращении.